# Optimistic locking for operations

Tags: java, jooq

I saw in the documentation the example of optimistic lock and it works:

```
// Properly configure the DSLContext
DSLContext optimistic = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.ORACLE,
  new Settings().withExecuteWithOptimisticLocking(true));
  
// Fetch a book two times
BookRecord book1 = optimistic.fetchOne(BOOK, BOOK.ID.eq(5));
BookRecord book2 = optimistic.fetchOne(BOOK, BOOK.ID.eq(5));

// Change the title and store this book. The MODIFIED value has not been changed since the book was fetched.
// It can be safely updated
book1.setTitle("Animal Farm");
book1.store();
```

But i have a question about optimistic locking with operations. As i see optimistic locking works only with store() methods.
Do I have a chance of optimistic locking this way:

```
dslContext.update(getIdField().getTable())
            .set(getEntityField(), dto)
            .where(getIdField().eq(dto.getId()))

  dslContext.batch(updateOperations).execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.16, jOOQ's optimistic locking is an `UpdatableRecord` only feature, meaning it applies to jOOQ-generated SQL queries that arise from your `insert()`, `update()`, `store()`, `merge()`, `delete()` calls on your record. It does not apply to any other queries.

In a future version of jOOQ, there might be a re-design of this functionality to use the new jOOQ 3.17 feature called ["client side computed columns"](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-computed/) ([#9879](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9879)). The re-design is tracked as [#13339](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13339). It may or may not ship with jOOQ 3.17. Once implemented, your arbitrary DML statement will be transformed in order to implement optimistic locking semantics.